# CDNs are working fine but not a local hosted script on ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, server, local, cdn

I've been trying to access any script in my ASP.NET (Web Forms) application but it doesn't work. I'm able to access the file through the server therefore the destination is fine but the file doesnt seem to be loaded locally.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

I've tried changing the access path and it doesn't change anything. Though, it works just fine if i use the CDN :

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

I've had this issue before as I have never been able to access any JQuery or Bootstrap locally hosted scripts. Though, I'm right now facing an issue as I need to modify a line in the .js file and can't do it with the CDN. Any ideas ?

Comment: Where is the `fullcalendar.js` script saved in your project? What folder?

Comment: it was previously in a script folder but since it wasn't working it's now on the root of the projet as the same level as the the page that is trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is *trying* to be called from the same directory as the ASPX page. If it's not in the same directory, then it will not load. When you load it from a CDN you have the full path and there's no 404 error.

If you use Chrome's dev tools (F12) or FireBug in Firefox then you should be able to see if it's a 404 error causing the problem.

You need to make it relative to the page or start from the root of the site.

If the script `fullcalendar.js` is in the root directory and the page is being called from `http://somedomain.com/apath/here.aspx` then it will fail.

To start from the root of your site, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

If it's in the root folder, or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

If it's in the `scripts` folder of your ASP.NET project.

If you just need to "go up" a level you can use (the `..` is to go up a folder)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, I had tried the use the / before when it was in a folder and it didn't access it, but on the root as /fullcalendar.js it has worked, thank you!

Comment: So if you wanted to keep it in the scripts folder, you'd use `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>` as the first `/` starts from the root directory

Comment: yeah but that didn't work so i'll just keep it in the root for now.

Comment: Make sure you do a `CTRL + F5` to refresh, so it doesn't use a cached page when changing bit like this!